# Heroku mecabインストール時にエラー

Tags: python, heroku, mecab

### 発生している問題・実現したいこと

requirements.txtに

```
mecab-python-windows==0.996
```

と記述して `git push` コマンドで mecab のインストールを試みたものの、

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mecab-python-windows==0.996
```

というエラーが返ってきました。
mecab を Heroku へインストールするにはどうすればよいのでしょうか。

---

### 追記

mecab-python3 としたところ

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-alv4puww/mecab-python3/
```

というエラーが返ってきました。このエラーを解消するにはどうすればよいでしょうか。

ログ:

```
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Collecting mecab-python3 (from -r /tmp/build_48589b6a2c92201982f5d27fbec47bfe/requirements.txt (line 3))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/25/e9/bbf5fc790a2bedd96fbaf47a84afa060bfb0b3e0217e5f64b32bd4bbad69/mecab-python3-0.7.tar.gz (41kB)
remote:            Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
remote:            /bin/sh: 1: mecab-config: not found
remote:            Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:              File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-build-btsgxibr/mecab-python3/setup.py", line 41, in <module>
remote:                include_dirs=cmd2("mecab-config --inc-dir"),
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-build-btsgxibr/mecab-python3/setup.py", line 21, in cmd2
remote:                return cmd1(strings).split()
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-build-btsgxibr/mecab-python3/setup.py", line 18, in cmd1
remote:                return os.popen(strings).readlines()[0][:-1]
remote:            IndexError: list index out of range
remote:
remote:            ----------------------------------------
remote:        Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-btsgxibr/mecab-python3/
```

Comment: HerokuのOSがWindowsではないのでは。その場合は、mecab-python の方を使います。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。今度は別のエラーが返ってきました。Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-dmrjovzp/mecab-python/これはどうすればよいのでしょうか。

Comment: python3であれば、mecab-python3の方をインストールしてみてください。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。mecab-python3と記述しましたが、Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-alv4puww/mecab-python3/というエラーが返ってきました。

Comment: エラーメッセージの上部に詳細なメッセージが表示されていませんか。その部分を質問に追加してもらえるとエラーの原因がわかるかもしれません。https://qiita.com/machine-absentstudent/items/b7a0721ad829f8cb6597 の記事が参考になるかも。

Comment: こちらには書ききれなかったので質問文にログを追加しました。

Comment: qiita.com の記事と同じエラーですね。mecabとmecab-ipadicをインストールする必要があるようです。

Comment: MecabをインストールするためにHerokuでbrew install mecab-ipadicのコマンドを投げればいいと思うんですけど。どうやってHerokuへコマンドを送ればいいのかわかりません。困りました。

Comment: 自分もHerokuを使ったことがないのでよくわかりません。別の人の回答を待ってください。

Comment: Herokuの件は新たな質問にするのもいいかもしれません。

Comment: そうですね、どうやってHerokuへコマンドを投げるのか質問を新たに作成します。コメントありがとうございます。